# Is there a way to programmatically export/save generated javascript and css bundles?

Tags: c#, javascript, css, .net-4.5, bundling-and-minification

I am using `System.Web.Optimization` `BundleTable` for CSS and JavaScript file bundling. I was able to save bundle files manually by going to `Chrome Developer Tools`, `Sources` tab then clicking on bundle I would like to save and then clicking right mouse button on code and `Save as` (screenshot below)

[image]

**I was wondering is there a way to save them programmatically** (javascript or .NET I don't mind ether) as I need to test changes in bundle files by comparing them with old versions to see if they have changed or not. The end product will be selenium test most likely.

Comment: Javascript can't save to a local file. But you can easily write something in Javascript/Greasemonkey that adds elements to the page, for your use, so you can rip (right click and copy) whatever you want.  But that doesnt sound like what you want. Any (real) programming language can be used easy enough to download the html files of a website and parse and save it out however you want.

Comment: what you use for creating bundle?

Comment: @Grundy .NET4.5 `System.Web.Optimization` `BundleTable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorted it out myself.

```
    public static string GetBundleContents(string virtualPath)
    {
        OptimizationSettings config = new OptimizationSettings()
        {
            ApplicationPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath,
            BundleTable = BundleTable.Bundles
        };

        BundleResponse response = Optimizer.BuildBundle(virtualPath, config);
        return response.Content;
    }

    public static void WriteBundlesToDisk(string path)
    {
        foreach (var bundle in BundleTable.Bundles)
        {
            var bundleContents = BundleConfig.GetBundleContents(bundle.Path);
            File.WriteAllText(string.Format("{0}/{1}.{2}", path, bundle.Path.Split('/').Last(), BundleConfig.GetFileExtensionByBundleType(bundle)), bundleContents);
        }
    }

    public static string GetFileExtensionByBundleType(Bundle bundle) 
    {
        if (bundle is ScriptBundle)
            return "js";
        else if (bundle is StyleBundle)
            return "css";
        return "folderBundle";
    }
```

usage:

```
BundleConfig.WriteBundlesToDisk("c://bundles");
```

sidenote: there's a type of bundle called `System.Web.Optimization.DynamicFolderBundle` that is not being handled properly by the solution above, it will save it as `.folderBundle` file type.

Comment: hi i am trying to the same, but i cant see GetBundleContents and GetFileExtensionByBundleType methods in my bundeconfig class. Can you edit your answer and put the bundle  config class you are using in answer here. thanks @Matas Vaitkevicius

Comment: @Alok Hi, I did this a year ago, for company i don't work for any more. Sorry.

Comment: no worries ,can you give me tips on how to achieve the same. once i complete my code i will post it here thanks

Comment: @Alok Hi, have a crack at this. http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification